# "I wish" in present or future?

Tags: british-english, subjunctives, future-tense

> I wish it were Friday tomorrow.

Or

> I wish it would/could be Friday tomorrow.

Which of these sentences is correct or are they both correct?

Comment: This is an ELL question. I wish tomorrow were Friday. I wish tomorrow could be Friday.  No would in this case. Please note: I wish you were rich but I wish you would/could stay. would only the conditional helping verb.

Answer (score 1):

> I wish it were Friday tomorrow.

This is correct.

> I wish it would be Friday tomorrow.

This sounds like you could have an option or ability to make tomorrow another day other than the day it will be and are trying to will that into existence.

> I wish it could be Friday tomorrow.

This sounds like someone or something other than you have an option or ability to make tomorrow another day other than the day it will be, and you want them to will that into existence.

As the last two statements are not true outside of fantasy or divine contexts, they sound odd, but not so odd that a listener/reader couldn't figure out you meant the first statement.

Comment: "Could be" is fine as well, but suggests that "Friday" is used in some non-literal sense. E.g. If you wished that you could be done with the work week after tomorrow, but cannot for whatever reason, you might express that as "I wish tomorrow could be Friday".

Answer (score 0):

I would understand any of the options you have given to have the meaning you are intending, but I would find:

> I wish it would be Friday tomorrow.

a little strange, so I suspect as [Lambie](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/33113/lambie) suggests in the comments, this is not technically correct. You would still be understood by almost all native English speakers I've ever encountered though.

Answer (score 0):

You usually say "Tomorrow is Friday" instead of "Friday is tomorrow".
You can also say "Tomorrow will be Friday", but it's not as common as "Tomorrow is Friday".

So it's more appropriate if you say:

I wish tomorrow were Friday.